# If amplitude and phase of a random signal are independent, then does real and imaginary parts of that signal are mutually exclusive (or) independent?

Tags: probability, random-variables, signal-processing

For a complex random variable If amplitude and phase of a random signal are independent,
then does real and imaginary parts of that signal becomes mutually exclusive (or) independent?

Comment: The signal could be presenting on a $\frac{\pi}4$ angle in the complex plane, making real and imaginary parts dependent, or it could be presenting along an axis...